# Incorrect result when use same alias name in HiveQL

Tags: hive

We have encountered a weird problem, which Hive returned incorrect result while use same alias name in subquery.

Following 3 SQL will return "A, C":

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT T1.C1, T2.C1 C2 
  FROM (SELECT 'A' C1) T1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'C' C1) T2 ON 1 = 1 
 WHERE **T1**.C1 = 'C') **T1**

SELECT * FROM (SELECT T1.C1, T2.C1 C2 FROM (SELECT 'A' C1) T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'C' C1) T2 ON 1 = 1 WHERE **T1**.C1 = 'C') **T2**

SELECT * FROM (SELECT T1.C1, T2.C1 C2 FROM (SELECT 'A' C1) T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'C' C1) T2 ON 1 = 1 WHERE **T2**.C1 = 'C') **T1**

Following 1 SQL will return "C, C":

SELECT * FROM (SELECT T1.C1, T2.C1 C2 FROM (SELECT 'A' C1) T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'C' C1) T2 ON 1 = 1 WHERE **T2**.C1 = 'C') **T2**

Comment: In Hive 1.2.0 the last query returns A, C

Comment: @leftjoin, thanks a lot. I will try the same SQL on 1.2. We are currently using Hive 1.1 with CDH5.12